# outofmemoryerror toString("UTF-8") ByteArrayOutputStream in android

Tags: android, out-of-memory

Here is the log:

```
03-28 19:12:29.083: E/AndroidRuntime(22004): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
03-28 19:12:29.083: E/AndroidRuntime(22004): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-28 19:12:29.083: E/AndroidRuntime(22004):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
03-28 19:12:29.083: E/AndroidRuntime(22004):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
03-28 19:12:29.083: E/AndroidRuntime(22004):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
03-28 19:12:29.083: E/AndroidRuntime(22004):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
03-28 19:12:29.083: E/AndroidRuntime(22004):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-28 19:12:29.083: E/AndroidRuntime(22004):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
03-28 19:12:29.083: E/AndroidRuntime(22004):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
03-28 19:12:29.083: E/AndroidRuntime(22004):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-28 19:12:29.083: E/AndroidRuntime(22004): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
03-28 19:12:29.083: E/AndroidRuntime(22004):    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:364)
03-28 19:12:29.083: E/AndroidRuntime(22004):    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:223)
03-28 19:12:29.083: E/AndroidRuntime(22004):    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.toString(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:175)
03-28 19:12:29.083: E/AndroidRuntime(22004):    at com.vtube.data.YoutubeAPI.doGetRequest(YoutubeAPI.java:71)
03-28 19:12:29.083: E/AndroidRuntime(22004):    at com.vtube.data.YoutubeAPI.getPopular(YoutubeAPI.java:86)
03-28 19:12:29.083: E/AndroidRuntime(22004):    at com.vtube.data.YoutubeAPI.getPopularEntry(YoutubeAPI.java:97)
03-28 19:12:29.083: E/AndroidRuntime(22004):    at com.vtube.app.BaseFourActivity$PageZeroRefreshTask.doInBackground(BaseFourActivity.java:358)
03-28 19:12:29.083: E/AndroidRuntime(22004):    at com.vtube.app.BaseFourActivity$PageZeroRefreshTask.doInBackground(BaseFourActivity.java:1)
03-28 19:12:29.083: E/AndroidRuntime(22004):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
03-28 19:12:29.083: E/AndroidRuntime(22004):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-28 19:12:29.083: E/AndroidRuntime(22004):    ... 4 more
```

I don't understand why this go wrong, this app not crash often, only in a few times. This happens when I leave the app for a while.
where the code went wrong:

```
public static String doGetRequest(String url) throws IOException{
        HttpClient lClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet lGetMethod = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse lResp = null;
        try {
            lResp = lClient.execute(lGetMethod);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
            Log.v(TAG, e1.toString());
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        ByteArrayOutputStream lBOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        String lInfoStr = "";

        if (lResp != null){
            try {
                lResp.getEntity().writeTo(lBOS);
                lInfoStr = lBOS.toString("UTF-8");
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return lInfoStr;
    }
```

`lInfoStr = lBOS.toString("UTF-8");` this paticular line

How can I solve this? Does `toString()` cost a lot of memory?

Comment: looks like the bytearray is huge and consuming a lot of memory..

Comment: What is going on when you leave the app for a while? Is it doing something you have not told us yet?

Comment: @Anukool yeah, how can I prevent this?

Comment: @greenapps no, just leave the device there, didn't touch it at all

Comment: So only one download will cause the memory shortage? Why would the error come after a while laying down after the download? Please be more precise.

Comment: @greenapps this runs in an AsyncTask which takes data from internet, maybe the internet wasn't so good, it took a long time to get the data. This does not happen all the time, but it happens

Comment: Judging by this line `com.vtube.data.YoutubeAPI.doGetRequest` you're trying to load an entire youtube video into a `String`. Of course that will kill your application. You shouldn't really even be loading it into a byte array.

Comment: @artbristol no, what I got is a youtube feed, not a video

Comment: @Wesley have you found solution?

Comment: @MalwinderSingh just use apache commons IO utils, you should be fine.